# linking css externally to html in vscode

Tags: html, css

Like a dummy I forgot to make a css file/sheet in vscode prior to beginning my project so I was writing css within my html. No biggie (I thought), I'll just create my CSS link and copy/paste. However, where my CSS worked for me before, while I was within my HTML screen, it no longer works for me in its proper CSS screen. Am I doing something wrong?

```
[what its supposed to look like and does while in html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIlsq.jpg)
[code in html screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3dZ0.png)
[me, cutting selected css code to transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSVKx.jpg)
[code in css screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43e9F.png)
[how it shows up now 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5EDz.jpg)
[how it shows up now 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJbsj.jpg)
```

I tried googling how to link css to html in vscode because I'm quite sure that's the main problem I am having, I even tried looking through my many tutorials I've subscribed to, I'm just at a loss and felt it was time for me to reach out before I started to cry, lol.

pls and ty in advance and also I'm so very sorry I'm not very good at asking questions yet, this is my first question ever as a newbie front-end dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try specifying relativity

If your CSS is within the same directory as your HTML you import like this;

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css" />
```

If your CSS is in a subdirectory but your HTML is at the top-level you import like this;

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./directory/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Or if your HTML is in a subdirectory and your CSS is at the top-level you import like this;

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css" />
```

If you don't want to bother with relativity, you can import from the root of your project;

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/subdirectory/style.css" type="text/css" />
```

*Also, `<link>` tags should still be in the `<head>` tag like you had it.*

*Also Also, Please include your code as text instead of images.*

Comment: omg ty ty! It worked! Also, I will make sure to take your advise and start including code instead of images.